# WordPress. Почему возникает ошибка доступа?

Tags: wordpress

Чистая установка. В functions.php пишу:

```
add_action('admin_init','add_admin_page');

function add_admin_page(){
    add_menu_page('Настрока темы', 'Настрока темы',10,'theme_settings','admin_page','',6);
}

function admin_page(){
    echo 'test';
}
```

Вроде все верно, но при переходе по этому пункту, WP сообщает:

> Извините, вам не разрешено просматривать эту страницу.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_menu_page

> Если вы видите ошибку `You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.` при попытке зайти на страницу, это значит, что вы подключаете функцию слишком рано, подключаете функцию не на нужный хук. Нужно использовать хук `admin_menu`.